# How to handle pages auto-updating during a script working through a list

Tags: python, selenium

I have a Python/Selenium script working through a page, and in an effort not to spam the server I have half second sleeps between interactions with page elements. I've noticed an issue where the script "lost track" of items in my list, and just recently discovered that it seems to be due to the page auto-updating/resetting during the script's run. The id's seem to be dynamically generated, so the refresh usually alters some of the id's, and the script crashes.

When I first encountered the issue, I just put a try-catch on it, skipping elements it had lost track of and logging an error, as I didn't have any real information on the issue and it was infrequent.

Giving it some more thought, and watching the script in action for a while, I noticed a slight refresh and the page re-ordering some elements.

The best idea I've come up with is below, where I reload the page entirely and refresh the list MID-LOOP and starting over. This is clearly a wrong way to address this. What is a better option?

```
        try:
            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
        except link_lost:
            print('Lost track of something...')
            browser.refresh() # Page glitch fix. Refresh, relocate buttons, start over.
            browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(5) # could be optimized by keeping track of which question we're on and starting from there
            target_buttons = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('[aria-label=target]')
```

Comment: Mulling it over today I realized if this works at all I should probably remove the browser.refresh() and just keep the target_buttons re-assignment.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily using selenium functions:

1. find parrent element of list and then go to the first element that want to click
2. using xpath find element that you want to click, save it's as variable

example:

```
add_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Dodaj")]')
contact_field = add_button[0].find_elements_by_xpath('.//parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*')
name_of_contact = contact_field[0].find_element_by_xpath('.//div/div/div/div/div/a')
```

3. for example, name_of_contact is your variable and contact_field is parrent element like list or window.
4. now just use contact_field[0].click() and no matter what happen it will be always first element from that list.
5. above you see it from two sides, add_button is the element on page, using it I find a parrent element of contact_field where were all info, then I find appropriate descendant (name_of_contact)

Comment: So I have been avoiding using xpath, it seems like it's pretty fragile if I'm understanding it correctly. You're basically hard-coding the path to the variables, right?

So you get your list (add_button), parent all the way to the top for contact field (which might refresh, afaik), then div all the way back down? I think I'm misunderstanding how your solution functions.

Comment: it was kind of idea how to solve the problem not the solve of problem. this script is pretty stable in my tests.